# react-admin support for WordPress API?

Tags: wordpress-rest-api, react-admin

My team is attempting to get react-admin working with the WordPress REST API. We need all the standard functionality you'd expect, including filtering, sorting, and associations.

The issue is that the WordPress REST API follows slightly different conventions than the data providers listed in https://marmelab.com/react-admin/DataProviders.html.

**An example inconsistency**

react-admin expects Header: `X-Total-Count`

WordPress uses Header: `X-WP-Total`

**Question**

Is there a best practice strategy for composing an existing data provider and only slightly tweaking it to work with the WordPress API? For example, mapping the incoming `X-WP-Total` header to `X-Total-Count`?

I appreciate any help on solving this problem, and I'll post any updates for future viewers, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else stumbles on this question: I was able to get a connection to the WP-JSON API working with the [tutorial code](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Tutorial.html) by copying the compiled data provider from `./node_modules/ra-data-json-server/lib/index.js` into my project root and changing 4 instances of `x-total-count` to `x-wp-total`.

Answer (score -1):

to solve this issue, i have replaced **X-WP-Total** occurrences by **X-Total-Count** in WP code base, and it's worked.

Thank you

Comment: It is no good idea to edit the core code directly for after the next wp update your changes will be gone..

Comment: i see, but i'm unable to change the WP Headers response !, do you have any idea?

Comment: I didn‘t try it but you can set your own headers with php header() function or overwrite already set headers. Have a look at the php manual page about header() if you know the total count you should be able to do it